# Scoped thread using modern C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++17, winapi

I wrote this simple scoped thread to use it as a class member to ensure the the thread running on a class method doesn't continue running after the class has been destructed.  Also to spawn threads from the `main()` function to ensure that I don't forget any running threads upon exit .

This can be achieved by calling `join()` method of the C++11 `std::thread` but I wanted a class that will automatically do this.

I didn't implement `detach()` function because I think this kills the purpose of a scoped thread; is this right?

I'd like to know if there is any bug, memory leak, other errors ...

```
#include <tuple>
#include <process.h>

extern "C"
{

    __declspec(dllimport)
        BOOL 
        __stdcall
        CloseHandle(
            HANDLE hObject
        );

    __declspec(dllimport)
        DWORD
        __stdcall
        WaitForSingleObject(
            HANDLE hHandle,
            DWORD dwMilliseconds
        );

    __declspec(dllimport)
        DWORD
        __stdcall
        GetCurrentThreadId(
            void
        );
}
template <class T, auto CloseFn>
struct HandleDeleter
{
    using pointer = T;
    void operator ()(pointer handle) { CloseFn(handle); }
};

using Handle = std::unique_ptr<void, HandleDeleter<HANDLE, CloseHandle>>;

inline std::error_code make_system_error(DWORD val) noexcept
{
    return std::error_code{ static_cast<int>(val), std::system_category() };
}

inline std::error_code make_system_error(int val) noexcept
{
    return std::error_code{ val, std::system_category() };
}


namespace LIB_NAMESPACE
{


namespace detail
{
    template <class Func, class ... Args>
    struct ThreadParams
    {
    public:

        ThreadParams(Func&& func, Args && ... args)
            : fn{ std::forward<Func>(func) }, args_tuple{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } 
        {}

        void Invoke()
        {
            std::apply(fn, args_tuple);
        }

    private:
        Func fn;
        std::tuple<Args...> args_tuple;
    };

    template <class ParamsType>
    unsigned __stdcall ThreadFunc(void* args)
    {
        auto params = reinterpret_cast<ParamsType*>(args);
        params->Invoke();
        delete params;
        return 0;
    }

}

class scoped_thread
{
public:

    using native_handle_type = Handle;
    struct thread_id
    {
    public:

        friend class scoped_thread;

        thread_id() = default;

        thread_id(unsigned int id) : id_{ id } {}

        thread_id(const thread_id&) = default;

        thread_id(thread_id&& other) noexcept : id_{ other.id_ }
        {
            other.invalidate();
        }

        thread_id& operator=(const thread_id&) = default;

        thread_id& operator=(thread_id&& other) noexcept
        {
            id_ = other.id_;
            other.invalidate();
            return *this;
        }

        ~thread_id()
        {
            id_ = 0;
        }

        unsigned int id() const { return id_; }

        bool operator==(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() == other.id();
        }

        bool operator!=(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() != other.id();
        }

        bool operator>(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() > other.id();
        }

        bool operator>=(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() >= other.id();
        }

        bool operator<(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() < other.id();
        }

        bool operator<=(const thread_id& other) const
        {
            return id() <= other.id();
        }

    private:

        void invalidate() { id_ = 0; }

        unsigned int * id_ptr() { return &id_; }

        unsigned int id_ = 0;
    };

    scoped_thread() = default;

    template <class Fn, class ... Args>
    scoped_thread(Fn&& fn, Args && ... args)
    {
        using ParamsType = detail::ThreadParams<Fn, Args...>;
        ParamsType* params = new ParamsType{ std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        thd_handle.reset(
            reinterpret_cast<void*>(_beginthreadex(nullptr, 0,
                detail::ThreadFunc<ParamsType>, params, 0, id.id_ptr()))
        );
        if (!thd_handle)
        {
            delete params;
            throw std::system_error(errno, std::system_category());
        }
    }

    scoped_thread(scoped_thread&&) = default;

    scoped_thread& operator=(scoped_thread&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (joinable())
            std::terminate();
        this->~scoped_thread();
        new (this) scoped_thread{ std::move(other) };
        return *this;
    }

    native_handle_type& native_handle() noexcept { return thd_handle; }

    const native_handle_type& native_handle() const noexcept { return thd_handle; }

    thread_id get_id() const noexcept { return id; }

    bool joinable() const noexcept
    {
        return get_id() != thread_id{};
    }

    void join()
    {
        check_if_valid_join();
        WaitForSingleObject(thd_handle.get(), std::numeric_limits<DWORD>::max());
        thd_handle.reset();
        id.invalidate();
    }

    ~scoped_thread()
    {
        if (joinable())
            join();
    }

private:

    void check_if_valid_join()
    {
        if (!thd_handle)
            throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code(std::errc::no_such_process));
        if (get_id() == GetCurrentThreadId())
            throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code(std::errc::resource_deadlock_would_occur));
        if (!joinable())
            throw std::system_error(std::make_error_code(std::errc::invalid_argument));
    }

    native_handle_type thd_handle;
    thread_id id;
};


}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but why couldn't `scoped_thread` be implemented in terms of `std::thread`?

Comment: It could, but I wanted to make use of the new language features and to be more familiar with templates

Answer (score 2):

Overall I think the code is pretty good and your use of the more modern features of C++ looks OK.

Still there are some things that could be improved. In no particular order I offer the following suggestions:

- The idea of a `scoped_thread` is good (also discussed in Effective
  Modern C++ item 37). Even if you want to implement your own
  `std::thread` replacement (for learning purposes or otherwise), I'd
  recommend splitting that part out and implementing `scoped_thread` in
  terms of it. That way you can re-use both classes in other contexts.
- I'd probably use either the functions from `process.h` or the raw
  Win32 API (i.e. `CreateThread`) not mix them.
- Speaking of Win32 API functions: Just include `windows.h`, don't
  do the declarations on your own.
- I realize including `windows.h` in a header file like this is pollutes
  the global namespace, so I'd create wrapper functions like
  `void native_start_thread(void (*)(void*))` etc. and place them in an
  accompanying C++ file.
- In modern C++ naked calls to `delete` are a code smell. You should always
  have the pointers owned by a `std::unique_ptr`. Of course you have to
  be careful in this case to not double delete objects. What I mean is:
  In `ThreadFunc` hand ownership to a `std::unique_ptr` and in the
  `scoped_thread` constructor store `params` in a `unique_ptr`. Use
  `get()` when creating the thread and then `release()` when the thread
  has been constructed (and thus has taken ownership of the memory).
- You should check the return value of `WaitForSingleObject`
- The code could use some more comments. For instance I had to look up
  whether 0 could be a valid thread id (it can't, but I couldn't
  remember that was the case).
- I can't see anything wrong with the code in this regard, but I'm not
  too fond of thread ownership actually being tied to the thread id.
- Again, I don't see any immediate problems, but I'd probably make sure
  to null out the thread handle in the moved from thread (to at least aid
  in debugging). This would mean using a non-defaulted move-constructor,
  and then I'd probably implement it in terms of the move assignment
  operator (which then wouldn't/couldn't use placement new, which again
  I think works fine, but seems "overkill" here).

Comment: "I'd probably use either the functions from process.h or the raw Win32 API (i.e. `CreateThread`) not mix them" . the docs recommends to start any thread that uses c runtime library using functions from `process.h` in order to avoid a small memory leak when the thread exits . for the last remark : it's already done because the thread handle is a smart handle (handle in a smart pointer) so the default `unique_ptr` move assignment operator nulls out (invalidates) the handle once moved from to ensure one object manages the handle . thanks for your tips .

Comment: @dev65: Sorry my bad on both counts. I mistakenly though the need to use `_beginthread` was gone, but it seems like that's not the case when [linking statically to the CRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitthread?redirectedfrom=MSDN). And in the heat of battle I'd forgotten that `native_handle_type` was a smart pointer - I'll amend my post later to reflect this.